# Invert Map<K, List<V>> to Map<V, K>

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

`map = mapOf((2: [3,4,5]), (7: [22,33,44]))`

need to convert this to

`mapOf(3:2, 4:2, 5:2, 22:7, 33:7, 44:7)`

tried using associate with forEach, not sure of the syntax

Comment: Please use valid Kotlin syntax if you're asking a Kotlin question. What happens if there are duplicate values in the inner lists?

Answer (score 4):

There might be some nicer syntax, but this should work well enough.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val map = mapOf(
        2 to listOf(3, 4, 5),
        7 to listOf(22, 33, 44)
    )
    val transformedMap = map.flatMap { entry ->
        entry.value.map { it to entry.key }
    }.toMap()
    println(transformedMap)
}
```

Prints
`{3=2, 4=2, 5=2, 22=7, 33=7, 44=7}`

Note that the `toMap` function states

> The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original collection. If any of two pairs would have the same key the last one gets added to the map.

So if you have the same value in two different lists, only the last one will be included in the map.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val map = mapOf(
        2 to listOf(3, 4, 5),
        7 to listOf(22, 33, 44),
        8 to listOf(3)
    )
    val transformedMap = map.flatMap { entry ->
        entry.value.map { it to entry.key }
    }.toMap()
    println(transformedMap)
}
```

Prints `{3=8, 4=2, 5=2, 22=7, 33=7, 44=7}`

Comment: `map.flatMap { (key, values) -> values.map { it to key } }.toMap()`

Answer (score 1):

Zymus' answer is correct, and is also what I would probably write.

However, if this is something that will be called often, you might want to extract it to a separate function that is more efficient.

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, Iterable<V>>.invert(): Map<V, K> {
    val newMap = mutableMapOf<V, K>()
    for ((key, iterable) in this) {
        for (value in iterable) {
            newMap[value] = key
        }
    }
    return newMap
}
```

Usage:

```
fun main() {
    val map = mapOf((2 to listOf(3, 4, 5)), (7 to listOf(22, 33, 44)))
    val inverted = map.invert()
    println(inverted)
}
```

Output:

```
{3=2, 4=2, 5=2, 22=7, 33=7, 44=7}
```

This is functionally equivalent to

```
map.flatMap { (key, values) -> values.map { it to key } }.toMap()
```

including the behaviour where if there are duplicate values in the original input, only the last one will be preserved as a new key. However, the `flatMap` version creates many temporary `List`s (the number of original keys + 1) and many temporary `Pair`s (the number of original values), whereas this iterative version creates no extra objects.